# Same format for rpc and database

Tags: nosql, protocol-buffers, rpc, thrift

I need to connect C++ application with other C++ and remote Java application as follows:

`1.C++ app --> 2.local sqlite Database --> 3.C++ sender --> 4.Java receiver`

So 1. app use sqlite api to store data to database that have some schema.
Next app 3. read that schema and translates it to thrift/rpc format so it could be send to app 4.

For me its painful to take care of schema in sqlite and schema in thrift/rpc format.
Is it possible or good practice to store data, not in sqlite, but in database in json format and use same format for rpc messaging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends a lot on what you're storing and how you access it.  If app (1) writes the whole database in one go, and app (2) simply reads the whole thing and sends it off, then there may be no reason to store your database in sqlite.  You can store it as a big Thrift, Protobuf, or JSON blob.  You probably want to store it in the same format that you use to send it between (3) and (4), so that no translation is needed.

But if app (1) needs to incrementally modify the database or read parts of it back later, or if app (2) needs to search the database for specific keys, then you might want to stick with sqlite.  Thrift, Protobuf, and JSON are all write-once formats -- you write an entire message in one go, and you read the message back all at once.  You cannot update such a file in-place; you have to read the whole thing into memory, modify it there, and then write a whole new file.  You also cannot efficiently search for specific rows -- again, you have to read the entire thing into memory at once.

But, yes, storing your database file in thrift/protobuf/json format rather than sqlite is absolutely a good practice if it fits with your use case.

BTW, another possibility is to store your database in sqlite format, but store individual rows as blobs that are themselves in Thrift, Protobuf, or JSON format.  For example, your database might only have two columns:  primary key, and "content" blob.  The content blob is a byte blob encoded in a different format, so that you don't have to tediously translate between schemas.  This way, you can still search your database by primary key.

Comment: 1. In fact, that sqlite is some kind of buffering in case of Java app is online. 2. Did you get into account that there is i.e MongoDB that has json format? Is it still write-once ?

Comment: If the purpose of the sqlite DB is just to be a buffer, then I think it definitely makes sense to skip sqlite and write directly in whatever format the eventual RPC will use.  And yes, you could use MongoDB to store the buffer, too, but that seems like it would be similar to storing encoded protobufs/thrifts as byte blobs in sqlite.  If it's just a buffer, you really don't need a DB at all.